# OpenCV Issue with imread() in an image from an absolute path after conversion from Unicode wchar_t

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, visual-c++

I am a beginner to win32 api and opencv working on an app which uses windows File Explorer to choose an image. I am using provided code from windows [GetFileNameFromHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/obtaining-a-file-name-from-a-file-handle) to get a complete path and then a function UnicodeToASCII to convert a wchar_t into ASCII-type char to ensure compatibility with opencv imread().

Before using imread i process the string further with fixPath to replace \ with / incase the string has readability issues, and lastly i run imread()

in console the path prints out as expected with no errors. I have also used std::filesystem::exists and returns true.

```
#ifndef UNICODE 
#endif

BOOL GetFileNameFromHandle(HANDLE hFile);

std::string UnicodeToASCII(const std::wstring& unicodeString) {
    std::string asciiString;
    for (wchar_t c : unicodeString) {
        if (c <= 0x7F) {
            asciiString += static_cast<char>(c);
        }
        else {
            asciiString += '?';
        }
    }
    return asciiString;
}
std::string fixPath(string input) {
    std::string result;
    for (char c : input) {
        if (c == '\\') {
            result += '/';
        }
        else {
            result += c;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
if (cvui::button(frame, 200, 50, 150, 50, "OK")) {
            
            std::string input = fixPath(UnicodeToASCII(pszFilename));
            std::cout << "\nPath: " << input << endl;

            if (filesystem::exists(input)) {
                std::cout << "\nfilesystem : EXISTS\n";
            } 
            // check existence
            else {
                std::cout << "\nfilesystem : DNE\n";
            }

            if (isASCII(input)) {
                std::cout << "\npath is ascii\n";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "\n path is not all ascii\n";
            }
            //check char type

            cv::Mat img = imread(input);
            
            if (img.empty()) { 
                std::cout << "\nCould not open or find the image" << endl;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Console Output:

`Selected C:\images\circle.jpg`
`Path: C:/images/circle.jpg`

`filesystem : EXISTS`

`path is ascii`
`[ WARN:0@3.487] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/images/circle.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity`

`Could not open or find the image`

if i instead run

`cv::Mat img = imread("C:/images/circle.jpg");`

in place of

`cv::Mat img = imread(input);`

which is the path it printed out, imread can read it and it works. Because of this I believe it is an error somewhere in the path conversion.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but I know that `fixPath` should be renamed to read `breakPath`. The path separator on Windows is a backslash. A forward slash is up for interpretation, and some APIs will translate it to a backslash, others won't, and some won't, depending on other parts of the string. Just remove it entirely and start over. This may or may not solve the issue. If it doesn't, at least there's one less code path to think through.